# How to describe the mapping from Random Variable $(X, Y)$ to a function of $X$? For example, $g(X):=E[Y|X]$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have random variables $X\in\mathbb{R}^p$ and $Y\in\mathbb{R}$, the conditional expectation $\operatorname{E}[Y|X]:=\operatorname{E}[Y|\sigma(X)]$ is a function of $X$.

Define $g(X):=\operatorname{E}[Y|X]$, then $g(\cdot)$ is a function $\mathbb{R}^p\mapsto \mathbb{R}$

Such an operator (taking conditional expectation) maps the random variable $(X,Y)$ to a measurable function of $X$.
I want to describe such operators in general, where the intention is to describe a class of predictors that can be derived from the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$.
Is it a mapping from Function Space to Function Space? Is there a professional name for this kind of operators?

Thank you so much for any comments!

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, and let $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. Conditional expectation $E(\cdot \mid \mathcal{G})$ is a projection mapping $L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ onto $L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)$.

Thus in your case, we can say $E(\cdot \mid \sigma(\cdot)) : L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) \times M(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^p) \to \bigcup_{X \in M(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^p)}L^1(\Omega, \sigma(X), P)$. I'm not really sure there is a name for this kind of object. There is a result that the measurable functions of $X$ are precisely the functions measurable wrt $\sigma(X)$.

Comment: What is $M(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^p)$? Random variables with values in $\mathbb{R}^p$? (With $(\mathcal{F},\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}^p))$-measurability implicitly assumed?)

Comment: I am not following your thought, because first you are mentioning projections, then you are saying you don't know a name for this kind of object. Can't you take $\mathcal{G}:=\sigma(X)$? Is this because you are concerned that there are $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ for which there are no measurable $X$ with values in $\mathbb{R}^p$ s.t. $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(X)$?

Answer (score 0):

Does the following definition of conditional expectation suffice?

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and let $\mathcal{G}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra contained in $\mathcal{F}$. For any real random variable $X \in L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, define $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ to be the unique random variable $Z \in L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)$ such that for every bounded, $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable $Y$, $E[XY] = E[ZY]$.

See the notes here for this definition and more: [https://galton.uchicago.edu/~lhttp://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/383/ConditionalExpectation.pdfalley/Courses/383/ConditionalExpectation.pdf](https://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Elhttp://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Elalley/Courses/383/ConditionalExpectation.pdfalley/Courses/383/ConditionalExpectation.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I think Mason's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4383260) should work for you: projection is the word you are looking for.

It is straightforward to define conditional expectations of $L^2$ random variables as (orthogonal) projections in $L^2$ (which is a Hilbert space). $L^1$ is not a Hilbert space, but $L^2$ is dense in $L^1$, and with some formal arguments the notion of projection extends from $L^2$ to $L^1$. If I remember correctly, you can find such detailed arguments in Kallenberg's book "Foundations of Modern Probability".

Note that WeakLearner's answer quotes another standard definition of the conditional expectation. The definitions are equivalent (and Kallenberg's book probably shows that).

Your question might've arisen in the context of Bayes-optimal decision rules: e.g., the optimal prediction of $Y|X$ under the quadratic loss function is $E[Y|X]$. These are minimisation problems. I hope someone comes and sheds light on the connection between minimisation and projection, which can be directly related to your question.